# How can I predict rigid-body movement in a multi-player network game using cannon.js?

Tags: prediction, cannon.js

How can I simulate rigid-body movement?  I'm building a multi-player network racing game and I need to predict the next millisecond physical behavior and send position/rotation over the network to reduce the synchronization movement gap.

My current implementation just sends my current position/rotation to the other player.  I can see the jerky movement on the other PC.  My guess is that the cannon simulation and the latest position/rotation have a conflict that causes the slight delay.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Added details to the title

Comment: thx guys for kind assistant